# Estimating differential regulation of metabolites in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, limma

I have a metabolite data set with 25 resistant and 25 susceptible lines. Data looks like this, every column is a line and every row is a metabolite:

```
> dput(head(df,20))
structure(list(Metabolites = structure(1:20, .Label = c("M001", 
"M002", "M003", "M004", "M005", "M006", "M007", "M008", "M009", 
"M010", "M011", "M012", "M013", "M014", "M015", "M016", "M017", 
"M018", "M019", "M020", "M021", "M022", "M023", "M024", "M025", 
"M026", "M027", "M028", "M029", "M030", "M031", "M032", "M033", 
"M034", "M035", "M036", "M037", "M038", "M039", "M040", "M041", 
"M042", "M043", "M044", "M045", "M046", "M047", "M048", "M049", 
"M050", "M051", "M052", "M053", "M054", "M055", "M056", "M057", 
"M058", "M059", "M060", "M061", "M062", "M063", "M064", "M065", 
"M066", "M067", "M068", "M069", "M070", "M071", "M072", "M073", 
"M074", "M075", "M076", "M077", "M078", "M079", "M080", "M081", 
"M082", "M083", "M084", "M085", "M086", "M087", "M088", "M089", 
"M090", "M091", "M092", "M093", "M094", "M095", "M096", "M097", 
"M098", "M099", "M100", "M101", "M102", "M103", "M104", "M105", 
"M106", "M107", "M108", "M109", "M110", "M111", "M112", "M113", 
"M114", "M115", "M116", "M117", "M118", "M119", "M120", "M121", 
"M122", "M123", "M124", "M125", "M126", "M127", "M128", "M129", 
"M130", "M131", "M132", "M133", "M134", "M135", "M136", "M137", 
"M138", "M139", "M140", "M141", "M142", "M143", "M144", "M145", 
"M146", "M147", "M148", "M149", "M150", "M151", "M152", "M153", 
"M154", "M155", "M156", "M157", "M158", "M159", "M160", "M161", 
"M162", "M163", "M164", "M165", "M166", "M167", "M168", "M169", 
"M170", "M171", "M172", "M173", "M174", "M175", "M176", "M177", 
"M178", "M179", "M180", "M181", "M182", "M183", "M184", "M185", 
"M186", "M187", "M188", "M189", "M190", "M191", "M192", "M193", 
"M194", "M195", "M196", "M197", "M198", "M199", "M200", "M201", 
"M202", "M203", "M204", "M205", "M206", "M207", "M208", "M209", 
"M210", "M211", "M212", "M213", "M214", "M215", "M216", "M217", 
"M218", "M219", "M220", "M221", "M222", "M223", "M224", "M225", 
"M226", "M227", "M228", "M229", "M230", "M231", "M232", "M233", 
"M234", "M235", "M236", "M237", "M238", "M239", "M240", "M241", 
"M242", "M243", "M244", "M245", "M246", "M247", "M248", "M249", 
"M250", "M251", "M252", "M253", "M254", "M255", "M256", "M257", 
"M258", "M259", "M260", "M261", "M262", "M263", "M264", "M265", 
"M266", "M267", "M268", "M269", "M270", "M271", "M272", "M273", 
"M274", "M275", "M276", "M277", "M278", "M279", "M280", "M281", 
"M282", "M283", "M284", "M285", "M286", "M287", "M288", "M289", 
"M290", "M291", "M292", "M293", "M294", "M295", "M296", "M297", 
"M298", "M299", "M300", "M301", "M302", "M303", "M304", "M305", 
"M306", "M307", "M308", "M309", "M310", "M311", "M312", "M313", 
"M314", "M315", "M316", "M317", "M318", "M319", "M320", "M321", 
"M322", "M323", "M324", "M325", "M326", "M327", "M328", "M329", 
"M330", "M331", "M332", "M333", "M334", "M335", "M336", "M337", 
"M338", "M339", "M340", "M341", "M342", "M343", "M344", "M345", 
"M346", "M347", "M348", "M349", "M350", "M351", "M352", "M353", 
"M354", "M355", "M356", "M357", "M358", "M359", "M360", "M361", 
"M362", "M363", "M364", "M365", "M366", "M367", "M368", "M369", 
"M370", "M371", "M372", "M373", "M374", "M375", "M376", "M377", 
"M378", "M379", "M380", "M381", "M382", "M383", "M384", "M385", 
"M386", "M387", "M388", "M389", "M390", "M391", "M392", "M393", 
"M394", "M395", "M396", "M397", "M398", "M399", "M400", "M401", 
"M402", "M403", "M404", "M405", "M406", "M407", "M408", "M409", 
"M410", "M411", "M412", "M413", "M414", "M415", "M416", "M417", 
"M418", "M419", "M420", "M421", "M422", "M423", "M424", "M425", 
"M426", "M427", "M428", "M429", "M430", "M431", "M432", "M433", 
"M434", "M435", "M436", "M437", "M438", "M439", "M440", "M441", 
"M442", "M443", "M444", "M445", "M446", "M447", "M448", "M449", 
"M450", "M451", "M452", "M453", "M454", "M455", "M456", "M457", 
"M458", "M459", "M460", "M461", "M462", "M463", "M464", "M465", 
"M466", "M467", "M468", "M469", "M470", "M471", "M472", "M473", 
"M474", "M475", "M476", "M477", "M478", "M479", "M480", "M481", 
"M482", "M483", "M484", "M485", "M486", "M487", "M488", "M489", 
"M490", "M491", "M492", "M493", "M494", "M495", "M496", "M497", 
"M498", "M499", "M500", "M501", "M502", "M503", "M504", "M505", 
"M506", "M507", "M508", "M509", "M510", "M511", "M512", "M513", 
"M514", "M515", "M516", "M517", "M518", "M519", "M520", "M521", 
"M522", "M523", "M524", "M525", "M526", "M527", "M528", "M529", 
"M530", "M531", "M532", "M533", "M534"), class = "factor"), R = 
c(-0.368417113, 
-0.101138639, -0.161723188, 0.202453574, -0.255021436, 0.990889582, 
-0.14527723, 0.079853308, 0.029544276, 0.441221431, -0.11944612, 
-0.305230969, 0.03355256, 1.03727535, 0.320838857, 0.057860187, 
-0.220164171, -2.526670332, -0.367387096, 0.802085235), R.1 = c(0.335923239, 
3.061811172, -0.035662198, -0.607682577, 0.777607579, -0.058005603, 
1.137154667, 1.023908735, 0.028284344, -0.044308897, -0.411500613, 
1.399836977, 0.439845793, 2.247067657, -0.742871026, 1.568088682, 
0.11575394, 5.04122684, 2.374395515, 1.541474963), R.2 = c(-0.005240453, 
-0.298993563, -0.033124556, 0.000437247, -0.363018191, 0.326128083, 
0.21257698, -0.205006227, -0.091374353, -0.370715168, -0.267458783, 
0.248780422, 1.630503285, 1.874717025, 0.069540933, -0.436639754, 
0.133565845, -2.078394913, 0.540959939, -0.190331212), R.3 = c(0.02178722, 
0.571957417, 0.00324566, -0.061805284, 0.162608704, -0.325539348, 
-0.053329502, 0.227249242, -0.025090981, -0.080247253, 0.144508557, 
-0.088720932, 1.263644554, 0.996155965, 0.210446023, 1.990889582, 
0.076457177, 4.421971981, 0.198741153, -0.855116946), R.4 = c(0.006111685, 
0.021758841, -0.00737953, 0.380875266, -0.276248724, -0.011315313, 
-0.107602955, -0.104603974, 0.343158603, -0.457723898, -0.03562391, 
0.193219285, -0.063940821, 0.149473244, -0.019274012, -0.676331271, 
0.512558704, -0.994071688, 0.059564554, 1.429864917), R.5 = c(0.166168642, 
0.037674433, 0.086877451, -0.231273643, 0.221108542, -0.186011986, 
-0.089551585, -0.061788592, -0.018223759, 0.071986113, 0.101146723, 
-0.049779048, -0.518114903, 1.253322095, 0.216780998, 0.165038055, 
-0.439934372, 0.382512734, 0.421213338, 1.001105937), R.6 = c(-0.232768963, 
-0.261850899, -0.142152384, -0.342128282, -0.207394664, 0.031122517, 
-0.088355874, -0.324414618, 0.083484986, -0.381236261, -0.11649968, 
0.124415109, 0.358689609, 1.043033998, 0.038236206, -0.996719549, 
-0.01579871, -1.273254248, 0.551507204, 0.900665975), R.7 = c(-0.121204957, 
-0.269377573, 0.025763096, -0.370846136, 0.288406834, 0.110607324, 
-0.076961982, -0.629167859, -0.265012055, -0.505201609, -0.023481433, 
-0.17856392, 0.865332323, 0.524969082, -0.291204505, 0.719516623, 
-0.012732085, -1.941620399, 0.663526717, 1.199444088), R.8 = c(-0.141327295, 
0.152181413, 0.153037654, -0.097868883, -0.191620073, 0.259454516, 
0.583256179, -0.772155023, 0.272534699, 0.814200162, 0.248763352, 
0.315661336, 1.902073579, 3.385926093, 0.53062173, 0.309248961, 
0.006293118, -2.517164686, 0.301678975, 0.353796149), R.9 = c(-0.384312139, 
0.06505404, -0.073435447, -0.715351781, 0.217991274, -0.304059998, 
-0.102759574, 0.231438468, -0.403444624, 0.294886468, -0.085702486, 
-0.480999914, -0.433684562, 0.7205518, 0.005892568, 0.731183242, 
-0.290235435, 1.642113301, 1.033423002, 0.404841732), R.10 = c(0.043284098, 
-0.187714919, 0.103755766, 0.494175476, 0.183367264, 0.048461489, 
0.341167603, 0.942935915, 0.231005552, -0.032843257, 0.110780431, 
0.369394834, 1.09200937, 1.745564723, 0.411796215, 0.852997588, 
0.335184192, -0.440708907, 0.203262185, 1.007914836), R.11 = c(0.083099508, 
0.267121498, 0.015533879, -0.144656445, -0.101470878, 0.222392421, 
-0.266252913, 0.890823438, -0.210945895, -0.848512247, -0.067114196, 
-0.25944549, 0.221455302, 0.806681407, -0.042501067, 0.260151897, 
-0.040791883, -1.787941649, 0.382274808, 0.938294929), R.12 = 
 c(-0.705217235, 
 2.542562534, -0.135227381, -0.443646178, 0.519586492, 0.043795118, 
 0.686317021, 1.041588324, -0.304393436, -0.234275413, -0.43566302, 
 1.195857383, 1.752478594, 1.497997192, -0.80811711, 1.677544508, 
 0.208963846, 3.621611552, 2.73039294, 0.799138017), R.13 = c(0.42312992, 
 0.183353267, 0.147085025, -0.266112283, 0.324924347, 0.183090771, 
 0.20325984, -0.250088093, -0.24489442, 0.005137198, -0.116409492, 
 0.03395771, 1.37097252, 1.869706252, 0.235820911, 1.090602549, 
-0.225066556, 1.028663758, 0.590223864, -0.134533181), R.14 = c(0.048153022, 
 0.279512674, -0.015087144, 0.345647904, -0.066420426, -0.099863894, 
 0.002270174, 0.663318138, -0.13597767, 0.122096476, -0.020838519, 
 0.128906398, -0.620454804, 2.291401419, 0.112474729, 0.093509451, 
 0.211284031, 0.57905586, 0.319030146, -0.748749321), R.15 = c(-0.019510824, 
 0.115344305, 0.004854839, -0.57797607, 0.242971645, -0.085664592, 
 -0.186912355, 0.411476387, -0.173219579, -0.575194724, -0.184830499, 
 -0.066941159, -0.832648942, 2.396326768, -0.120558924, 1.286370872, 
 0.137328874, -0.415249645, -0.123145792, 0.396469739), R.16 = 
 c(0.123458788, 
 0.237039197, 0.092887298, -0.079751022, 0.056754778, -0.445799753, 
 0.013420516, 0.100152869, 0.119695066, -0.15320627, 0.009168315, 
 -0.17625064, -0.029486765, 1.666907682, 0.276289737, 1.188035155, 
 0.046047368, 0.280843392, 0.542246519, 0.847685006), R.17 = c(0.108754902, 
 0.020919096, -0.122974045, -0.280708392, -0.288840707, 0.084474568, 
 -0.295709099, -0.398888114, -0.644341048, -0.775756783, -0.548916159, 
 -0.180266946, -0.564083771, 1.007945835, -0.250767066, 0.229068486, 
 -0.272062897, 0.545069774, -0.590980007, 0.286389802), R.18 = 
 c(-0.819717423, 
 0.946193556, -0.096635783, -0.397640449, -0.404948682, -0.005217709, 
 0.361129545, 1.449898022, 0.076338824, -0.689502486, -0.437063806, 
 0.886017472, 0.837525303, 1.192266964, -1.132614108, -3.602036014, 
 0.368129605, -3.349106876, 1.454669286, 1.465455406), R.19 = c(0.620445088, 
 -0.415932471, 0.112894056, -0.15182218, 0.174272257, 0.111202562, 
 -0.840963315, -1.107727456, 0.105602182, -0.255257055, 0.280560458, 
 -1.043602781, -0.090670359, 1.593968549, 1.352097575, 0.586873898, 
 -0.219566377, -0.725140159, 0.324350757, 1.013175389), R.20 = 
 c(0.245063967, 
 0.113375519, 0.092986888, 0.288600861, -0.02038524, 0.004543925, 
 0.190331212, -0.199632058, 0.018920862, 0.222392421, 0.130545468, 
 0.138523024, 0.984010269, 1.984278002, 0.042850965, 0.983598393, 
 0.098937541, 0.548928809, 0.083001425, -0.042997405), R.21 = c(0.661566826, 
 0.119437254, 0.091438651, -0.715355635, 0.061747686, -0.744882623, 
 -0.024626971, 0.12485642, -0.591404712, -0.368052144, -0.195621484, 
 -0.112050968, 1.025425329, 0.453802053, -0.254558205, 0.155103041, 
 -0.045724139, -0.266813345, 0.513923164, 0.730513197), R.22 = c(0.34075977, 
 0.290896243, 0.099535674, 0.0828218, 0.081235304, 0.139222747, 
 -0.0077634, 0.336721484, -0.055014102, -0.174725988, 0.016240641, 
 -0.10410469, -1.439586959, 1.326737974, -0.078921802, -0.053470209, 
 0.154328146, 0.149227196, 0.418521645, -0.324534591), R.23 = 
 c(-0.007948753, 
 0.17967325, 0.015206413, -0.127001855, -0.094574813, 0.334241356, 
 0.124851487, 0.128964093, -0.031364171, -0.467678979, 0.001269419, 
 -0.010840947, -0.265703593, 1.368883853, -0.116494992, -0.392426988, 
 0.063286245, 0.067375329, 0.338763899, 1.268311492), R.24 = c(-0.206450877, 
 -0.277674691, -0.049784833, 0.227339641, 0.077055427, 0.454548402, 
 0.26706616, 0.102023049, 0.016301812, 0.518421645, 0.032254199, 
 0.117301336, 1.246234735, 1.851766791, 0.151897009, 0.120904889, 
 -0.091315167, -2.760725806, 0.960369191, 1.034626343), S = c(0.402177532, 
 0.420055574, 0.176453044, 0.198545679, 0.697700712, 0.257629601, 
 0.041820176, 1.020353532, -0.208399149, 0.137707165, 0.201996393, 
 0.048339534, -0.707179047, 2.282832351, 0.028758993, 1.288589164, 
 -0.078759733, -0.186109073, 0.344746177, -0.552074207), S.1 = 
 c(1.203313446, 
 0.466087228, 0.587909785, 0.849665727, 0.927068478, 0.900155762, 
 0.666443903, 0.587368998, 0.707134371, 0.583025997, -0.00695835, 
 0.577717726, 0.725546578, 1.901779685, -0.21032333, 0.319245674, 
 0.109198771, -1.136286206, -0.647850963, 0.374345671), S.2 = 
 c(-0.875181736, 
 0.65620627, -0.028983688, -0.135730534, 0.358207527, -0.15277028, 
 -0.067694407, -0.55682075, -0.056583528, 0.738471539, 0.104744105, 
 -0.62940378, 0.028515371, 1.857176942, 0.533757723, 0.450724355, 
 -0.312065883, -0.176636838, 0.457017571, 0.9536772), S.3 = c(0.588257773, 
 -0.004822383, 0.053954091, 0.084236537, 0.460311579, 0.125835216, 
 0.096404484, -0.355126928, 0.21176328, 0.234658286, -0.27556876, 
 0.415037499, 1.357233048, 1.305564649, -0.465708593, 1.262304112, 
 0.110473998, 1.171660703, 0.415336783, 0.837677625), S.4 = c(0.741814035, 
 4.425151813, 0.16639331, 0.078002512, 1.210404071, 0.470250842, 
 1.341152662, 1.190877372, 0.329602023, 1.182913983, 0.023918627, 
 1.744449024, 0.894972523, 3.493155756, -0.620596763, 2.040804149, 
 0.236774856, 2.586085658, 2.247754539, -0.254284144), S.5 = c(0, 
 0.007502765, -0.028720823, 0.004278881, -1.099986727, 0.15926652, 
 -0.047631122, -0.020210187, 0.229170954, 0.115369782, 0.131861561, 
 -0.307095488, 0.137154667, 2.853523128, 0.329790213, 1.451427879, 
 0.056204602, -1.178436104, 0.217307132, -0.13196534), S.6 = c(-0.097674532, 
 0.204931451, -0.051225323, -0.113849077, -0.304976169, -0.218640286, 
 0.068503564, -0.112268983, 0.115141225, -0.075998876, 0.101573667, 
 0.053061244, 2.147169087, 1.947962735, -0.03231389, 0.932885804, 
 0.342297684, -2.342396544, -0.179376477, 0.47767359), S.7 = c(0.478736427, 
 0.097003889, 0.096215315, 0.45495651, 0.050843677, 0.106915204, 
 0.087578298, 0.140944127, 0.052787414, -0.027338709, 0.124964208, 
 0.270931736, -0.178294391, 1.769631783, 0.078304995, 0.471482646, 
 0.272772601, -1.593511279, 0.386425363, 0.0138058), S.8 = c(-0.156557778, 
 0.044163331, -0.010018756, -0.144204723, -0.032552115, -0.639055204, 
 0.187733306, 0.272767852, -0.118499236, 0.153039566, -0.023246344, 
 -0.01053836, 0.438884241, 1.547487795, 0.290668675, -0.294716135, 
 -0.171756995, -4.196230266, 0.155476957, 1.36156786), S.9 = c(0.03088456, 
 0.026459045, 0.026537138, 0.280405137, -0.151398317, -0.285216317, 
 -0.085020584, -0.227058321, 0.037186602, -0.157265791, 0.163116612, 
 0.242552369, -0.185978979, 2.27217506, -0.03099791, 1.119271892, 
 0.010281641, -0.858385395, 0.680822516, 0.869603363), S.10 = 
 c(-0.933612603, 
 -0.561661401, -0.010971118, 0.084506296, 0.327996931, -0.127379306, 
 0.372832796, -0.496799668, 0.306224012, 0.774497651, -0.016301812, 
 0.118511278, 1.584962501, 1.104115103, 0.371968777, 0.84789681, 
 -0.422532036, -0.165301976, 0.360402243, 1.316057507), S.11 = 
  c(0.158086968, 
 -0.16276126, 0.058752587, 0.334639147, -0.236693103, 0.19592021, 
 0.189362494, -0.170716666, 0.412125904, -0.186556808, 0.019746348, 
 0.513638785, 0.979906429, 0.711042249, -0.196017653, 1.536277987, 
 0.278880442, 0.2421449, -0.140854662, -0.892002748), S.12 = c(-0.103349527, 
 0.008171537, 0.00740795, 0.230358731, 0.008814865, 0.059265949, 
 0.256748143, -0.029081064, 0.058693994, 0.245492585, -0.046478319, 
 -0.272943002, 0.266249071, 0.438993478, 0.214384273, 0.174833802, 
 -0.107021711, 0.025829916, 0.547141035, -0.018962311), S.13 = 
  c(0.098720989, 
  0.087518126, -0.036205038, -0.096469371, 0.154284035, 0.144596821, 
  0.03090228, 0.137503524, -0.100928909, -0.111945526, -0.099622711, 
  -0.060255248, -0.3379805, 1.422995021, 0.06065222, 0.439371453, 
  -0.038819249, -1.051399153, -0.190932002, -0.564482695), S.14 = 
 c(0.181128626, 
 0.048144347, 0.082784875, 0.164744762, -0.192795853, 0.679907305, 
 -0.013862653, 0.446737964, 0, -0.340500201, -0.063834709, -0.039999772, 
 -0.476580935, 1.429061666, 0.043243186, 0.96893928, 0.027823682, 
 -1.492793697, 0.316419333, 0.409292824), S.15 = c(0.038395379, 
 0.001808342, 0.119825623, 0.175174518, 0.030871971, 0.976623217, 
 0.131155431, 0.157773076, 0, 0.265868136, 0.180653687, 0.240570256, 
 1.327638515, 2.925137937, 0.09894185, 1.495915625, 0.236760712, 
 -1.783214151, 1.440123224, -1.006173287), S.16 = c(0.26489715, 
 0.618994392, 0.119147265, 0.428553572, -0.112110366, -0.053977621, 
 0.152664728, -0.740156602, 0.222392421, 0.121136438, 0.074861437, 
 -0.037941572, 0.025671408, 2.236333895, 0.212915143, 0.991816796, 
 0.226770862, -2.156734325, -0.168712606, 0.53196331), S.17 = c(0.195724471, 
 0.004644926, 0.055255112, 0.160263427, 0.020340448, 0.36325156, 
 0.180808289, 0.010481859, 0.086611107, 0.071709873, 0.119690699, 
 0.180955701, 0.64309333, 3.040632365, 0.243708653, 1.188487452, 
 0.141495436, 1.260289029, 0.635859213, 0.152117679), S.18 = c(-0.209778803, 
 -0.194816177, -0.06734922, -0.157660246, -0.322157988, -0.085877835, 
 -0.164075926, 0.322299716, -0.145776183, -0.044931851, 0.10228105, 
 0.049327712, 1.003411973, 1.339959808, 0.104617003, 0.650394253, 
 -0.03789984, -3.153164235, 0.831164535, 0.715554624), S.19 = c(0.121624202, 
 0.227489373, 0.129994473, 0.185885669, 0.013160365, 0.054966459, 
 0.067986838, 0.266339551, 0.123382416, 0.075101455, 0.180398333, 
 0.355694209, 0.178705887, 1.356842621, -0.14448904, -0.343652866, 
 0.32081973, -0.410169692, 1.146938038, 0.791776524), S.20 = c(-0.078601215, 
 0.831950488, 0.058102955, -0.486632366, 0.507899167, -0.036069255, 
 0.508578267, 0.725146477, -0.648288436, 0.047828525, -0.39820306, 
 0.663167328, 0.688127986, 2.014873276, -1.228761946, 1.194816177, 
 0.037371429, -0.00250093, 2.610433188, 0.941635837), S.21 = c(-0.658223681, 
 0.514305072, 0.071083098, -0.535674538, 0.508087425, -0.118021974, 
 0.031406847, -0.220352916, -0.327403225, 0.059973955, -0.142100162, 
 -0.283264771, -0.295316365, 1.163403665, 0.085747948, -0.622437206, 
 -0.283547003, -3.427114726, 0.503542524, -0.194592393), S.22 = 
 c(0.502575109, 
 0.214738849, 0.16387432, -1.058339765, 0.314335635, 0.400198512, 
 -0.134555177, 0.525833289, -0.471621028, -0.19065835, -0.096404484, 
 -0.250315154, -2.200389125, 1.296830599, -0.194787667, 0.704871964, 
 0.100567477, -1.596585726, -0.285145107, 0.873242858), S.23 = 
 c(-0.60259496, 
 -0.301673433, -0.116609187, 0.255225081, -0.263307928, -0.124370693, 
 0.174581628, -0.232733207, 0.190477241, 0.380540255, -0.074136422, 
 0.087765536, 1.566966071, 1.595043184, 0.05055783, 0.612866668, 
 -0.19426882, -0.358166123, 0.577028319, 0.528832273), S.24 = c(0.041270996, 
 -0.129181684, -0.059588796, -0.003285788, -0.175620198, 0.422784607, 
 -0.068934631, 0.059378547, 0.03562391, -0.034765418, -0.068083945, 
 0.065987814, -0.291090691, 1.771431998, 0.046542586, -0.876278566, 
 0.276660352, -4.220478101, -0.018334524, 0.793037619)), row.names = c(NA, 
 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to find the metabolites that show significant difference between resistant and susceptible lines. Can anyone please guide me how to do that in R?

I don't know how to do this, so I first averaged each 25 lines in two sets into two data columns and then used #limma package in #R to check it out using this code:

```
 Group <- factor(c("R","S"))
 design <- model.matrix(~0 + Group)
 colnames(design) <- gsub("Group","", colnames(design))
 fit <- lmFit(dset[,2:3],design)
 contrast.matrix<-makeContrasts(RvsS=R-S,levels=design)
 fit2<-contrasts.fit(fit,contrast.matrix)
 fit2<-eBayes(fit2)
 sel.diif<-p.adjust(fit2$F.p.value,method="fdr")<0.05
 deg<-eset[,2:3][sel.diif,]
```

It gave following error:

```
 Error in .ebayes(fit = fit, proportion = proportion, stdev.coef.lim = stdev.coef.lim,  : No residual degrees of freedom in linear model fits
```

Comment: Please provide reproducible example and expected output. Also please describe what you want to do. *I want to find the metabolites that have different regulation between resistant and susceptible lines* is not a description. Lastly and most importantly, post the code you tried and pinpoint on that code where it failed.

Comment: @Sotos: Sorry for inconvenience. I will edit the question to try to make it clearer.

Comment: Hi Luqman, you want to test how many metabolites show a significant difference between resistant and susceptible lines? If so, the last_number doesn't quite make sense

Comment: @StupidWolf: Hi, Thanks for your response. From "last_number" I mean that it can be any number (10, 20, 40) given how many have differential regulation exactly as you say. Please guide me how to check this out.

Comment: @Sotos: If you find the question clear enough now, please suggest something.

Comment: @StupidWolf: If you find the question clear enough now, please suggest something.

Comment: Ok i see now, next time provide the code from the start.. You should not average.. I try to answer it below with an example. The original dataframe with 50 columns, (let's call it df), can you do dput(head(df,20)) and paste it as part of your question?

Comment: @StupidWolf: I have re-edit with "dput(head(df,20))". Apologies for the inconvenience, I am new here and do not quite know how it works.

Comment: No worries, see below whether it works for u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find metabolites that have different regulation, you are right to use limma. You don't need to calculate the mean. limma estimates the variance and means of your different samples, and test for significant difference based on that. I show you an example below, and you should be able to adapt it to your data:

```
#simulate data like yours
set.seed(100)
df = matrix(rnbinom(500*50,mu=100,size=2),500,50)
colnames(df) = paste(rep(c("R","S"),each=25),rep(1:25,2),sep="")
rownames(df) = paste("M",1:500,sep="")

#let's make M451 - M500 higher in "S"
df[451:500,26:50] <- df[451:500,26:50]+ rnorm(50*25,100,10)

library(limma)
# you need to set it up like this
Group <- rep(c("R","S"),each=25)
design <- model.matrix(~Group)
# voom to transform your data for lmFit
y <- voom(df, design)
fit <- lmFit(y, design)
fit <- eBayes(fit)
results <- topTable(fit,coef=2,number=nrow(fit))
head(results)

        logFC  AveExpr        t      P.Value    adj.P.Val         B
M452 1.967264 10.79952 6.509923 1.575131e-09 7.875653e-07 11.460506
M499 1.519837 11.02627 5.833641 4.228481e-08 6.726602e-06  8.320806
M485 1.760947 10.90720 5.809568 4.737771e-08 6.726602e-06  8.224170
M487 1.592874 11.09243 5.782545 5.381282e-08 6.726602e-06  8.089156
M470 1.727917 10.96071 5.719957 7.218783e-08 7.218783e-06  7.821371
M468 1.409254 11.13993 5.471017 2.282249e-07 1.695397e-05  6.702534
```

In the results table above, for example the first row M452, the first column tells you logFC S / R , a positive means it is higher in S compared to S. The other columns P.Value and adj.P.Val as p.values from the moderated t-test and the adjusted p.value to get the significant hits, do:

```
sum(results$adj.P.Val<0.05)
[1] 51
rownames(results)[results$adj.P.Val<0.05]
 [1] "M452" "M499" "M485" "M487" "M470" "M468" "M484" "M474" "M497" "M496"
[11] "M475" "M469" "M488" "M457" "M454" "M467" "M489" "M453" "M493" "M482"
[21] "M479" "M472" "M461" "M494" "M473" "M498" "M465" "M476" "M455" "M500"
[31] "M451" "M481" "M5"   "M456" "M495" "M490" "M486" "M471" "M462" "M492"
[41] "M459" "M464" "M478" "M460" "M466" "M152" "M458" "M483" "M480" "M491"
[51] "M255"
```

Using the example you have:

```
Group <- rep(c("R","S"),each=25)
design <- model.matrix(~Group)
# you don't need to use voom, but better to provide a matrix
mat = as.matrix(df[,-1])
rownames(mat) = df$Metabolites
fit <- lmFit(mat, design)
fit <- eBayes(fit)
results <- topTable(fit,coef=2,number=nrow(fit))
#gives you significant results
results[results$adj.P.Val<0.05,]
```

Comment: Hi dear, thank you so very much for your time and help. Now, I can surely reproduce this for my other data sets too. There is, however, one more thing. "results[results$adj.P.Val<0.05,]" returned 0 rows. That means there is no significant observation in the data at adjusted P-value, right?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Yes that means no significant hits. Which is quite unlikely given that you have 25 vs 25.. Is your input matrix normalized? I did not do that because I see negative values which is weird..

Comment: Let me tell you the whole thing. I feel that I have made a mess of it. I initially had a data of whole population (324 samples) before and after inoculation of disease. I then extracted the log2FC (from wild to mutant) which are the values that you see above. After that I extracted the data for resistant and susceptible samples (25 each) to see which metabolites vary among them. Above here are log2FC (from wild to mutant) and then 25*25 resistant and susceptible which now show no difference I assume. Where did I go wrong or is it all wrong?

Comment: you cannot give limma logFC values. Read the limma manual, I am sure there are models that describe your scenario? Just use raw data and go at it again... There should be differences

Comment: In that case, what change should I do make for normalization as you indicated?